# Firefox slow load time high Waiting/Receiving

Tags: performance, firefox

Website generally loads fast in under 4 seconds or less but on the odd occassion - usually every 1 out of 10 tries its reaching 20+ seconds. All i can spot is an unusually high waiting/receiving time in chromes dev tools. Web host says everything is fine and nothing looks out of the ordinary but clearly there is an issue.[image]
What could be causing such a long waiting/receiving time?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out in the end it was PHP's session lock limit.